# socket recvfrom() hanging/blocking when trying to capture UDP or multicast data in python

Tags: python, sockets, udp, multicast

First, I want to show that my interface w/static IP 10.10.10.88 is receiving the data, so I don't see how this can be a firewall issue:
[Packets in Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjMdv.png)

Wireshark is not running when I run the following code.

My programs are hanging when they call `recfrom()`. Here's an example of looking for traditional UDP broadcast, as shown in the image linked above from IP 10.10.10.120 to 255.255.255.255 port 2222:

```
import socket

# IP address associated with the network interface
ip_address = '10.10.10.88'  
port = 2222  # port I'm listening on

# Create a UDP socket and bind it to the IP address
udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind((ip_address, port))

print(f"Listening for UDP packets on {ip_address}:{port}")

try:
    while True:
        print('test1')
        data, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)  
        print('test2')
        
        # Print the received packet data as hexadecimal
        print(f"Received packet from {addr}: {data.hex()}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Capture stopped by user (Ctrl+C).")

udp_socket.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
Listening for UDP packets on 10.10.10.88:2222
test1
```

...and it just hangs forever. I can't even use Ctrl+C to get out of it--I have to kill the process.

When I try to see the multicast packets (see Wireshark snippet above) from IP 10.10.10.101 to 238.1.0.101 port 50101, I have the same issue with this code:

```
import socket
import struct

# Specify the multicast group address and port
multicast_group = '238.1.0.101'
multicast_port = 50101

# Create a UDP socket
udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Set the socket to allow reuse of the address (in case it's used by other processes)
udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind the socket to the specified multicast address and port
udp_socket.bind(('', multicast_port))

# Set the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option to join the multicast group
mreq = struct.pack('4sl', socket.inet_aton(multicast_group), socket.INADDR_ANY)
udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

print(f"Listening for multicast packets on {multicast_group}:{multicast_port}")

try:
    while True:
        print('test1')
        data, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)  
        print('test2')
        # Print the received packet data as hexadecimal
        print(f"Received packet from {addr}: {data.hex()}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Capture stopped by the user (Ctrl+C).")

udp_socket.close()
```

Output:

```
Listening for multicast packets on 238.1.0.101:50101
test1
```

Again, it hangs and I cannot Ctrl+C out of it.

Please help me
.

Comment: What does your client code look like?  I only have one system, but binding to `'0.0.0.0'` (or just `''`) and sending from a client to `('localhost', 2222)` works with your code otherwise.  You don't need to bind to a specific address.  If you do, it has to be an address on the **server** and it will **only** listen on that address instead of *all* interfaces (such as localhost).  Show a [mcve] of both the client and server code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Solve the hanging by using `select.select([udp_socket], [], [], timeout)` and polling for ready-to-recv packets.  Then CTRL-C and CTRL-BREAK will work.

Comment: The multicast code is working as well on my single machine.  What is your test setup?

Comment: Or solve it by setting a read timeout with `SO_RCVTIMEO`.

Comment: Or use `.settimeout()`.  Both setting the socket option and `.settimeout` will require a try/except to handle the TimeoutError.  `.settimeout()` is more portable as Windows and *nix take different parameters (DWORD vs. struct timeval).

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have an Ubuntu VM using tcpreplay on a shared internal network interface to replay a pcapng. My python code is on the host windows system. The packet replayer works with other stuff I've written using pyshark/tshark. Thanks for your comments--I'll check some of this stuff tomorrow.